# "No matching signature" error on adding a chrome.webRequest listener

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have this code:

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function(details){
  console.log(details);
});
```

I'm trying to understand and use the chrome.webRequest API. I can't figure why the code isn't working, I just wanna give a try to the API by logging all the requests made by chrome. I've set the permissions in my manifest on these two patterns `http://*/*` and `https://*/*` but i will always get this error from my background script: `Uncaught TypeError: No matching signature.` Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

"No matching signature" means you're passing the wrong parameters. As you can see in the documentation's [concepts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#subscription) and [examples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#examples) you need to specify at least two parameters. The documentation for individual methods doesn't mention that which is really confusing, and you can report it on https://crbug.com.

```js
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
  function(details) {
    console.log(details);
  },
  {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}
);
```

To view the background script's console see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10258029).

Comment: Yes, I was reading the method documentation and it's not specified that the callback take two params. Thank you.

Comment: It is documented here: http://chrome-apps-doc2.appspot.com/extensions/webRequest.html#subscription

Comment: @noam, the answer already has the correct documentation links.